# Unison conflict between new files and merge setting

Tags: macos, unison

I'm synchronizing my Sites folder on two Macs in the local network. Some Wordpress sites in this folder contain `readme.txt` files that are different because of different plugin or theme versions on the two Macs. They differ in file size and timestamp.

My `default.prf` has a setting for merging `.txt` files:

```
merge = Name *.txt -> diff3 CURRENT1 CURRENTARCHOPT CURRENT2 > NEW
```

which works fine for most text files, but not for these `readme.txt` files. When I start syncing, Unison gives me merge errors for these files. Here's a typical output:

```
Contacting server...
Connected [//mac1.local//Users/timm -> //mac2.local//Users/timm]
Looking for changes
  Waiting for changes from server
Reconciling changes

local          mac1.local
new file <-M-> new file   Sites/wp-sites/example.dev/wp-content/plugins/kocuj-sitemap/readme.txt

Proceed with propagating updates? [] y
Propagating updates

UNISON 2.48.4 started propagating changes at 15:21:22.86 on 16 May 2017
Merge command: diff3 '/Users/timm/Sites/wp-sites/example.dev/wp-content/plugins/kocuj-sitemap/.unison.merge1-readme.txt'  '/Users/timm/Sites/wp-sites/example.dev/wp-content/plugins/kocuj-sitemap/.unison.merge2-readme.txt' > '/Users/timm/Sites/wp-sites/example.dev/wp-content/plugins/kocuj-sitemap/.unison.mergenew1-readme.txt'
Merge result (exited (2)):
diff3: missing operand after `/Users/timm/Sites/wp-sites/example.dev/wp-content/plugins/kocuj-sitemap/.unison.merge2-readme.txt'
diff3: Try `diff3 --help' for more information.

Saving synchronizer state
Synchronization incomplete at 15:21:24  (0 items transferred, 0 skipped, 1 failed)
  failed: Sites/wp-sites/example.dev/wp-content/plugins/kocuj-sitemap/readme.txt
```

I realise that merge must fail on new files, but I'd think that the program should copy them over rather than trying to merge. I even tried ignoring the (pretty much useless) files:

```
ignore = Name {Sites/*/readme.txt}
```

but for some reason Unison doesn't ignore them. The thing is, I need text file merging because I rely on simple text files for my documentation. The `default.prf` looks like this:

```
# default profile

servercmd=/opt/local/bin/unison

root = /Users/timm/
root = ssh://mac2.local//Users/timm/

path = Sites

auto = true
times = true

# ignore permissions
perms = 0
rsrc = false

ignore = Name {.DS_Store}
ignore = Name {.localized}
ignore = Name {*/*.app/*}

ignore = Name {*/temp/*}
ignore = Name {*/cache/*}

ignore = Name {Sites/*/wp-content/languages/*}
ignore = Name {Sites/*/wp-content/plugins/*}
ignore = Name {Sites/*/wp-content/themes/twenty*}
ignore = Name {Sites/*/wp-sites/wordpress/*}

# ???
ignore = Name {Sites/*/readme.txt}

# diff and merge
diff = diff
merge = Name *.txt -> diff3 CURRENT1 CURRENTARCHOPT CURRENT2 > NEW
backup = Name *.txt
backupcurrent = Name *.txt
maxbackups = 10

log = true
logfile = /Users/timm/.unison/unison.log
```

I'm running Unison 2.48.4 on Mac El Capitan 10.11.6.

Did I overlook a setting? Is there any other way to make Unison copy and not merge new files?